# Next JS Redux not update server store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, next.js

The Redux Update operations I made on the client-side in Next JS are not updated in the server store.

Hello. I have a problem. I'm developing an SSR application with Next JS. I have provided the next js link with the next-redux-wrapper. State update operations can be provided. State updates I made on the server-side can be viewed on the client-side. The redux updates I made on the client-side also appear on the client-side, but when I refresh the page, it returns to the previous position. Sample scenario:

Users have addresses. Their addresses can be taken from the DB and printed on the screen. DB updates when I add a new address or delete the old address. Along with it, it is updated in the store on the client-side. So far there is no problem. However, when I refresh the page, for example, if there are 4 addresses before updating and I deleted one, after the refresh, it is printed as 4 addresses again. It continues like this until I get data from the server again.

How can I move the client-side store updates to the server-side without having to make requests to the server over and over again?

store.js

```
// store.js
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { createWrapper } from "next-redux-wrapper";
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk'

//  ROOT REDUCERS
import rootReducer from "../reducers";

const bindMiddleware = (middleware) => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
        const { composeWithDevTools } = require('redux-devtools-extension')
        return composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
    }
    return applyMiddleware(...middleware)
}

const store_ = (initialState) => {
    return createStore(rootReducer, initialState, bindMiddleware([thunkMiddleware]));
}

const wrapper = createWrapper(store_/*, { debug: true }*/);

export {
    wrapper
}
```

_app.js

```
// _app.js
const MyApp = ({props, Component, pageProps }) => {
    const store = useStore();
    if (!store.getState().R_PageSettings.initStore)
    {
        store.dispatch({
            type: HYDRATE,
            payload: {
                ...props.initialState
            }
        })
    }
    return (
        <>
        <Head>
          <title>{ variables.meta.title }</title>
        </Head>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
        </>
    )
}

const wrappedApp = wrapper.withRedux(MyApp);

export default wrappedApp;

wrappedApp.getInitialProps = async ctx => {
    const data = await wrapper.getServerSideProps(
        async (req) => {
            const { store, ctx } = req;
            const reduxStates = store.getState();
            let user = reduxStates.R_User.user;
            if (!user)
            {
                const cookies = parseCookies(ctx);
                if (cookies.usr && user !== undefined)
                {
                    const getUser = await CustomersController.tokenLoginControl(cookies.usr);
                    if (getUser && getUser.status)
                    {
                        store.dispatch(setUserSSR(getUser.user))
                        user = getUser.user;
                    }
                    else
                        destroyCookie(ctx, 'usr');
                }
            }

            return {
                user
            }
        }
    )(ctx)

    return data;
}
```

action.js

```
//  CONSTANTS
import {
    C_User
} from "../constants";

export const setUserSSR = user => {
    return {
        type: C_User.SET_USER,
        payload: {
            user
        }
    }
}

export const setUser = user => dispatch => {
    return dispatch({
        type: C_User.SET_USER,
        payload: {
            user
        }
    })
}
```

addresspage.js

```
// addresspage.js
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";

//  COMPONENTS
import UserPageLayout from "../UserPagesLayout";
import {
    CustomerAddressForm
} from "../../../components";

//  CONTROLLERS
import {
    CustomersController
} from "../../../controllers";

//  ACTIONS
import {
    setUser
} from "../../../actions";

const MyAddressPage = connect(({ R_User }) => {
    return {
        R_User
    }
}, dispatch => {
    return {
        setUser: bindActionCreators(setUser, dispatch)
    }
})((props) => {
    const addAddressHandle = () => {
        props.fullBarOpen(
            <CustomerAddressForm confirmHandle={async (address, setLoading) => {
                    const execute = await CustomersController.addAddress(address);
                    if (execute.status)
                    {
                        await props.setUser(execute.user);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        setLoading(false);
                    }
                }}
            />
        );
    }

    return (
        <UserPageLayout>
        </UserPageLayout>
    );
})

export default MyAddressPage;
```

Comment: use getServersideProps to pre hydrate on the server.

Comment: Are you sure my problem is related to this? I set the default redux states with getInitialProps in _app.js. I can then update redux on client side. But when I refresh the page, it goes back to its previous state. What I want to do is to be valid when the page is refreshed when there is an update on client side.

Comment: Have you fix it?